# Объединение колонок в словарь

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вида, БД - postgresql:

> `car    | name   | count`
>
> `Volga  | Vasya  |  1`
>
> `Volga  | Ivan   |  3`
>
> `Toyota | Sergey |  2`

Необходимо получить таблицу:

> `car    | name`
>
> `Volga  | {'Vasya': '1', 'Ivan': '3'}`
>
> `Toyota | {'Sergey': '2'}`

То есть, объединить два столбца в словарь (или в подобную структуру), и сгруппировать по первому.

Я пытался объединять через `jsonb_agg((name, count))`, но на выходе получаются данные вида `[{'f1': 'Vasya', 'f2': '1'}, {'f1': 'Ivan', 'f2': '3'}]`, а хотелось бы как в примере, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

*Как обычно, задаю вопрос и сразу же ответ находится, до этого искал, ни в какую.*

В общем, в моем случае надо использовать `jsonb_object_agg(name, value)`